# Return local square from grid in Haskell

Tags: string, list, haskell, return, extract

I have the following grid:

```
[["a1","b1",    "c1","d1"],
 ["a2","b2",    "c2","d2"],

 ["a3","b3",    "c3","d3"],
 ["a4","b4",    "c4","d4"]]
```

and would like to extract a range of values in their 'squares' so I end up with a list of square values. The x-values are horizontal and y-values are vertical.

I have the following function started:

```
type Coordinate = (Int,Int)

return :: [[String]] -> Coordinate -> [String]
return grid (x,y) = .....
```

where (0,0) is the top left corner of the grid. Using the above function I would like to be able to extract a square so I get like this (if my coordinates are (2,0), (3,0), (2,1), (3,1)):

```
["c1","d1","c2","d2"]
```

I have tried some methods including the `map` function but need some tips on how to proceed.

Comment: Did I understand right, that the size of the local square should always be `n/2 * n/2`, when the squares size is `n * n`?

Comment: @phynfo I think so. I'm pretty sure that's right!

Comment: You're trying to extract values from the grid, right? So the grid won't always be in such repetitious order? Because right now, we could convert (x,y) values into "letter-number" values just by counting the letters of the alphabet appropriately, without looking at the grid at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest the following:

```
localSquare :: [[a]] -> (Int,Int) -> [[a]]
localSquare xss (x,y) = map (take y . drop n) $ (take x . drop n) xss
  where n = length xss `div` 2

matrix = replicate 10 [1..10]
```

applied:

```
> localSquare matrix (5,5)
[[6,7,8,9,10],[6,7,8,9,10],[6,7,8,9,10],[6,7,8,9,10],[6,7,8,9,10]]
```

If you indeed need a plain list, apply just type `concat $ localSquare matrix (5,5)`

Comment: I don't think that's what I'm quite after here.

Comment: We haven't used the `$` symbols at all

Comment: `f $ x` is the same as `f x` or `concat $ localSquare matrix (5,5)` is the same as `concat (localSquare matrix (5,5))`. I.E. you can use `$` to avoid parantheses and to make your code more readable...